# How to detect release/dev mode in GoLang?

Tags: go

I have 2 config files for dev and release mode but I don't know how to implement them with specify mode:

```
release.config.yml
debug.config.yml
```

How can I detect Go dev/release mode? Or anyway to use config files like this?

Comment: What tool are those config files for?

Comment: For database, logs, port... just app settings

Comment: Use system env? or other root config?

Comment: I want to use all of them

Comment: How do you define the modes?  Do you use an environment variable, command line flag, or something else?

Comment: That's not how such stuff should be done (even if common in other languages). If you need a different _executable_: Use build tags to compile in more or less code. Adaption to different _environments_ typically happens through environment variables and or command line flags. In case of a _lot_ of configurations maybe a command line flag for the path to a configuration file (like yours).

Comment: Just pass the path of the config file as an argument to the process. That's your "mode" (if by "mode", you mean the contents of the config file, like your question suggests)

Answer (score 1):

There's no Go standard library facility for switching between configs depending on environment (as e.g. in Node world) as different users have probably different needs for this. Some frameworks (if you decide to use them) might offer this as their own feature.

Depending on your needs you might consider passing environment name as command line `-flag` or `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` value or somehow else detecting it depending on your actual use case and then based on detected environment read relevant config file.